# Question about semigroups of permutations

Tags: symmetric-groups, semigroups

Consider a semigroup $A\subseteq Sym(X)$. For $a,b\in A$, say that $a\leq b$ iff $b=ac$ for some $c\in A$. Suppose that $\leq$ is a linear order on $A$. Does it follow that $A$ is abelian?

Comment: Is $X$ finite??

Comment: Not necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is negative. Let $G$ be a non commutative [totally bi-ordered group](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Totally_ordered_group), for instance the free group with two generators. Let $P = \{x \in G \mid x \geqslant 1 \}$ be the set of positive elements of $G$. Then $x \leqslant y$ if and only if $x^{-1}y \in P$. In particular, there exists $z \in P$ such that $y = xz$.
Conversely, if there exists $z \in P$ such that $y = xz$, then $z = x^{-1}y$ and hence $x^{-1}y \in P$.
It follows that $P$ is a non commutative totally bi-ordered monoid in which $x \leqslant y$ if and only if there exists $z \in P$ such that $y = xz$.

Finally, by [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a permutation group and thus $P$ can imbedded into this permutation group.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know whether $\leq$ being a linear order on $A$ implies that $A\cup\{1\}\cup\{a^{-1}:a\in A\}$ is a group? (The reason I was interested in commutativity is that it suffices for it being a group, but that also seems to be true in your non-commutative example.)